# How do I construct the Maxwell tensor $\bf{^*F}$ from Fadaray one $\bf{F}$ in a non-flat spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations

In the book Gravitation (Misner, Throne and Wheeler), it's said that to consider the line element of the  flat space on the derivation of Maxwell tensor $\bf{^*F}$ from the Fadaray tensor $\bf{F}$ (text before equation 4.15).

How do I construct the Maxwell tensor $\bf{^*F}$ from Fadaray one $\bf{F}$ in a non-flat spacetime, once the unique equation presented in Gravitation is using the "Levi-Civita tensor" $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$ by

$^*F_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{1}{2}F^{\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$

and not the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: The metric tensor is contained in $\epsilon$, see the [definition of the Hodge dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual).

Comment: I'm not sure what the question here is. Is this a question about something specific in MTW or a more general question on how to calculate the Maxwell tensor in a non-flat spacetime?

Comment: @0celo7, my question is about your second option: thank you to clarify my own doubt. Let me modify my question for increasing clarity.

Comment: I didn't realize that the $^*$ was the Hodge star operator. With you reference, @ACuriousMind, my doubt is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once $^*$ is the [Hodge star operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual), its definition in non-flat spacetime

$(\star \eta)_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_{n-k}} = \frac{1}{(k)!} \eta^{j_1,\ldots,j_k}\,\sqrt {|\det g|} \,\epsilon_{j_1,\ldots,j_k,i_1,\ldots,i_{n-k}}$

say that we only need the determinant of the metric tensor $\bf{g}$ to change from $\bf{F}$ to $\bf{^*F}$.

Thanks for @ACuriousMind and @0celo7 for the help.

Answer (score 1):

$F_{\alpha \beta}=\frac 1 2 \epsilon_{\alpha \beta \mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ is general tensor equation so it is true in all frame both flat and curved spacetime. We can write it also as
$F_{\alpha \beta}=\frac 1 2 \sqrt{|g|}\varepsilon_{\alpha \beta \mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ ,where $\varepsilon_{\alpha \beta \mu\nu}$ is a Levi-Civita symbol. In the case of flat spacetime you just change $g\longrightarrow \eta$